# How to mock datetime in just one file?

Tags: python, mocking

I have two files in which I use `datetime`. Is there a way to mock it in just one file and not the other? Following is an example of where I'm seeing a weird behavior.

**File: test_file_one.py**

```
import datetime as dt
def print_datetime():
    print 'First: {}'.format(dt.datetime.utcnow())
```

**File: test_file_two.py**

```
import datetime as dt
def print_datetime():
    print 'Second: {}'.format(dt.datetime.utcnow())
```

**File: main.py**

```
import test_file_one as first
import test_file_two as second
import mock
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@mock.patch('test_file_one.dt.datetime')
def main(mock_datetime):
    mock_datetime.utcnow.return_value = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
    first.print_datetime()
    second.print_datetime()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
First: 2018-06-12 08:12:43.838243
Second: 2018-06-12 08:12:43.838243
```

As you see, both return the same datetime which was mocked.

1. Why are both mocked?
2. How to limit the mock to just one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add as many results you calls you want to do to [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)

```
mock_datetime.utcnow.side_effect = [datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1), datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=2)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I never knew you could do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to reduce the scope of your mocking.

Now you are applying your mock to the whole method by using the decorator `@mock.patch('test_file_one.dt.datetime')`

Instead you could try something like:

```
def main(mock_datetime):
    with mock.patch('test_file_one.dt.datetime') as mock_datetime:
        mock_datetime.utcnow.return_value = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
        first.print_datetime()

    second.print_datetime()
```

As an alternative, you could use `fake_time` method from `libfaketime-tz-wrapper` library.

Then your approach would be something like:

```
from libfaketime_tz_wrapper import fake_time

def main(mock_datetime):
    with fake_time(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)):
        first.print_datetime()

    second.print_datetime()
```

I didn't test if my suggestions work, but I've been using `fake_time` a lot in the last 1,5 year and seems to be very handful on issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `fake_time` looks interesting. Reducing the scope is not always possible in real-case scenarios. For example, if the method in the first file calls the method in the second file (and I still want to mock the datetime just in the first file), reducing scope does not work (with `mock` or with `fake_time`). How do you go about in such a scenario?

The problem, I feel, is how the `mock` library works. When I am mocking for one file, it should not mock in another file (I guess). I'd like `mock` to be more explicit, that is, mock only in files I explicitly mention.

Comment: I see, @Siddharth. Indeed sometimes we can't reduce scope, but wouldn't this be a bit of code smell? 
The mocking library works in a way that everything under that context will be wrapped into the parameters and values defined in the mocking. So, if you mock something for a file, scope remains mocked until it ends or another mocking comes into place. Maybe rewrite the methods for a better separation of concerns?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily tell it's code smell in all the cases. Specially when using external libraries. Let's say you have a function that gets the `utcnow` and then constructs an object (from an external library, say `Schematics`). The underlying library could very well do something like `isinstance(d, datetime)` for type-checking. Now mocking `datetime` in my method would affect the underlying library functionality as well.

Comment: @Siddharth what about use [`side-effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) feature?